# How to open Windows file editing app from WSL

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

[This answer](https://superuser.com/a/1311416) states that the following will be possible:

> For example, from the WSL command line you'll be able to type `code /mnt/c/Users/username/src/windows-file.txt` to open a Windows file in
> VS Code, or type `code /home/username/src/linux-file.txt` **to open a
> Linux file in VS Code.**

is it already possible with the newest WSL 2 and Windows 11 21H2?

At this point what I can do from inside WSL is to open the folder like this:

```
explorer.exe .
```

Which is already pretty awesome. But it would be even better to instead of running:

```
nano myfile.txt
```

open the file in Notepad++:

```
notepadpp myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can run any Windows executable this way.

`notepad.exe myfile.txt` will work, for example.

If your Notepad++ is in your `PATH`, then `notepad++.exe` would work too - mine isn't, though, so I have to use the full path:

```sh
/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe myfile.txt
```

You can of course create a shell script or an alias to shorten this command.

Just note that if you specify a file with a *path* then you will have an issue because the Linux path is passed verbatim to the Windows executable, but that can be fixed with `wslpath`.

Here is an example shell script that you could put into `~/bin/notepadpp` for example:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe "$(wslpath -w "$1")"
```

Comment: great, thanks! it appears the `.exe` extension is required, unless I create an alias. _If your Notepad++ is in your PATH_ - Windows or WSL `PATH`?

by the way, do you know how does it work? Through P9 as described in the answer I linked?

Comment: "`.exe` is required" - yes, because it's part of the filename. It's no different with any other executables in Linux - if your script is called `test.sh` you also need to use `test.sh` and not just `test` to run it. "WIndows or WSL `PATH`" - any, because the Windows `PATH` will be merged into your WSL `PATH` when you start the session. "How does it work? Through P9?" - yes: https://www.tiraniddo.dev/2019/07/digging-into-wsl-p9-file-system.html - plus, `.exe` is registered with `binfmt` to trigger an interop call to Windows.

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot of the valuable information and the link!